# Автодополнение шаблона html страницы

Tags: html, css, автоматизация, emmet

Знаю, что с помощью (emmet - html:5+Tab) можно вставить шаблон html страницы. Какие есть еще средства автодополнения шаблона страницы (желательно, чтобы автодополнение было как можно большим)?

Comment: вы можете добавить свой шаблон в редактор и вызывать его горячими клавишами, как это сделать - нагуглите

Comment: Есличо, вместо `html:5`,Tab можно использовать `!`,Tab. А простых способов расширения сокращений эммета увы нет (исп. сокращения редактора, aka кодсниппеты - в VS Code, например, они работают через автокомплит, то есть почти как встроенный эммет... Настройку сниппетов в этом редакторе можно открыть командой "Configure user snippets": F1,`>er sn`,Enter. Можно прописать и табстопы в шаблоне, чтобы мышкой не тыкать).